# How to combine results from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to print data from multiple tables in single with given date range

Tables

```
Users (PF_NO,NAME,DESIGNATION,LEVEL,DUTY_TYPE)
Holiday(id, DATE,PF_NO,Reason)
entry(id, DATE, PF_NO, f1,f2 etc)
```

I only mentioned required fields, All tables are connected by `PF_NO` ,
So basically I want to get details like below

`| PF_NO | NAME | DESIGNATION |LEVEL |DATE| DUTY |DUTY_TYPE|REASON| F1|F2|`

So scenario here is if user has entry in `Holiday` table for a given date then it will show `No` and `REASON` will contain REASON from `Holiday` table and the fields after reason will be blank, if he don't have an entry in a given date in `Holiday` table he has an entry in table `entry` then `DUTY` will be `Yes` and `DUTY_TYPE` will be printed from `users` table and other details from table `entry` will be printed, & I want to generate a report from given dates. Please help me

What I Tried?

```
NAME_OF_STAFF,PF_NO,DESIGNATION,LEVEL,BASIC,MOBILE,EMAIL 
from user 
Join holidays on(holiday_reason BETWEEN From_Date and To_DATE)


Select NAME_OF_STAFF,PF_NO,DESIGNATION,LEVEL,BASIC,MOBILE,EMAIL 
from user 
join holidays on id,PF_NO 
join holidays_reason on ID 
where date between
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would also make your question much clearer.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, but I thought query will be same in both, SO more people can see

Comment: This should be a simple LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Can you please help me? I'm beginner in this

Comment: Thanks Sir, I tried but I'm new in JOINS, I will share What I tried

Comment: [SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` with both `Holiday` and `entry` tables. You can then use `IFNULL()` to either show `Holiday.reason` or `users.Duty_type`

Comment: Ok, I updated question with what I tried

Comment: @Barmar can you have a look? I updated question

Comment: It looks like you don't even know the correct syntax of a JOIN. You need to learn the basics.

Comment: What is `holidays_reason`? That's not one of the tables you listed at the beginning of the question.

Comment: I tried in example but nothing to do with db,

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.PF_NO,A.NAME,A.DESIGNATION,A.LEVEL,B.DATE,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(B.id,0)<>0  THEN 'No' 
         WHEN ISNULL(B.id,0)=0  &&  ISNULL(C.id,0)<>0  THEN 'Yes' END Duty, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(B.id,0)=0  &&  ISNULL(C.id,0)<>0  THEN ISNULL(A.Duty_type,'') ELSE '' END Duty_type, 
    ISNULL(Reason,'') as Reason, ISNULL(C.F1,'') C.F1,ISNULL(F2,'') F2
FROM user A LEFT JOIN holiday B on B.id = A.PF_NO 
          LEFT JOIN holidays_reason C on C.ID=A.PF_NO
where C.date BETWEEN From_DATE and To_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I'm facing issue "  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'
"

Comment: If you want I can provide you the export file of db

Comment: I think he's usage of `ISNULL` is for MSSQL. In MySQL `ISNULL` takes one parameter. So you need to remove the second parameters of `ISNULL`s and change the results accordingly, have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Comment: Change `ISNULL(B.id,0)<>0` to `ISNULL(B.id) = 0` and `ISNULL(B.id,0)=0` to `ISNULL(B.id)=1`.

Comment: Or just `B.id IS NOT NULL` or `B.id IS NULL`